# during button click load the same page using php

Tags: php

I have a signup page designed with PHP and HTML for back end connectivity.

After the button click is made entering the details, I display the message `Success` on the same page with the help of JavaScript.

I need the details to get stored after the button click (its working fine), what I want is after the button is clicked and the PHP database page is opened. I don't want that page to be opened after the button click.

The same signup page should be retained with the entered information saved in the database.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: We have no idea why. Maybe we will know if you paste some code.

Comment: You will have to post the relevant parts of your code such as the JavaScript being used the HTML form and the response page so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: You can use header('Location:your_login_page'); on your php page

Answer (score 0):

So right now, on submit, it goes to a page that stores all the data and displays a "database page". But you don't want it to do that, you just want it to go back to the index page, or to a page that says success. Correct?

If that's the case, you can use this on your "database page".

```
header('Location:http://yoursite.com/path/to/login.php');
```